# C# winui 3 route event from component control to parent custom control

Tags: c#, custom-controls, winui-3

Using C# winui 3 (.NET 6), I have written a custom control `CommonButtonControl` made up of a `Button` containing an `Image` and a `TextBlock`. The idea is that I can keep a consistent look and feel for all buttons in my app and simplify my xaml so I only need to add the `CommonButtonControl` with values for `ImageSource`, `Text`, and `Command`.

All working fine so far, but I would also like to add a `Click` event which would get triggered on `CommonButtonControl` when the component `Button Click` event gets triggered. This would be to add consistency with the standard `Button` control and allow me to catch the `Click` event from `CommonButtonControl` to do such things as showing a confirmation Dialog before doing anything else.

I have added a `Click` event to my `CommonButtonControl` class. However I have the xaml for `CommonButtonControl` defined in a `DataDictionary` (as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-csharp-winui-3)), and when I try to catch the `Click` event for the component `Button`, it will only call code that is in the code behind the `DataDictionary` - not code that is in the `CommonButtonControl` class. There does not appear to be any way to call the `CommonButtonControl` object to tell it that the component `Button` event has fired so that I can raise the `CommonButtonControl Click` event. Any suggestions? It seems conceptually incorrect to add a `RoutedEventHandler` as a `DependencyProperty`.

**Resource Dictionary**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.DataTemplatesDictionary"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views">

    <Style TargetType="local:CommonButtonControl" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CommonButtonControl">
                    <Button
                        Command="{x:Bind Command, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Click="Button_Click">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Width="32"
                                Height="32"
                                Source="{x:Bind ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                                />

                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="8,0,0,0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Code behind resource dictionary**

```
partial class DataTemplatesDictionary
    {
        public DataTemplatesDictionary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //how to route this to the OnButtonClick method in CommonButtonControl?
        }


    }
```

**CommonButtonControl class**

```
public sealed class CommonButtonControl : Control
    {
        #region members

        private DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Text),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CommonButtonControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        private DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(CommonButtonControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

        private DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CommonButtonControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

        #endregion

        #region properties

        private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //how do I call this method when the component button click event is raised?
            Click?.Invoke(this, new());
        }


        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion



        public CommonButtonControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CommonButtonControl);
        }
    }
```

**Usage 1 - via Command (works)**

```
           <local:CommonButtonControl 
                Command="{x:Bind _app.DeleteItemCommand}"
                Text="Delete Item"
                ImageSource="{x:Bind _app.DeleteIcon}"
                />
```

**Usage 2 - via Click Event (how to get this to work?)**

```
            <local:CommonButtonControl 
                Click="CommonButtonControl_Click"
                Text="Delete Item"
                ImageSource="{x:Bind _app.DeleteIcon}"
                />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your `Button`, let's say "ButtonControl",

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomButton">
                <Button x:Name="ButtonControl" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

then you can get it in your custom control class and subscribe to **ButtonControl**'s `Click` event:

**CustomButton.cs**

```cs
public sealed class CustomButton : Control
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomButton);
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler? Click;

    private Button? ButtonControl { get; set; }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (ButtonControl is not null)
        {
            ButtonControl.Click -= ButtonControl_Click;
        }

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(ButtonControl)) is Button button)
        {
            ButtonControl = button;
            ButtonControl.Click += ButtonControl_Click;
        }
    }

    private void ButtonControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Click?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks! I had tried to make OnButtonClick public in the CommonButtonControl so I can bind to it from the template xaml (which works) but I like your solution better since it keeps the method private.